# How to get the Monte Carlo Standard error of bias?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, statistics

I am working on getting the expression of Monte Carlo Standard error (MCSE) of the bias. For a paramter $\theta$, the bias of $\theta$ is
$$
Bias=E[\hat{\theta}]-\theta
$$
The Monte Carlo estimate of Bias is given by
$$
\widehat{Bias}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{1=1}^n(\hat{\theta_i}-\theta)
$$

I do not know how to get the MCSE is given by
$$
\sqrt{\frac{1}{n(n-1)}\sum(\hat{\theta_i}-\bar\theta)^2}
$$
where $\bar\theta$ is the average of $\hat{\theta}_i$, $\bar\theta=\frac{1}{n}\sum \hat{\theta}_i$

---

If I am right. The definition of MCSE is
$$
MCSE(Bias)=\sqrt{\frac{Var[\widehat{Bias}]}{n}}
$$
Here
$$
Var[\widehat{Bias}]=Var[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{1=1}^n(\hat{\theta_i}-\theta)]=\frac{1}{n}Var[\hat{\theta_i}-\theta]=?
$$

So now my question is why
why the estimate of $Var[\theta_i-\theta]$ is $$\frac{1}{n-1}\sum (\theta_i-\bar \theta)^2$$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X_1,\dots,X_n$ be i.i.d. with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, and consider the sample mean $\bar{X}= n^{-1} \sum_iX_i$. Then $\text{var}(\bar{X}) = \sigma^2/n$.

How would we estimate this variance in practice? The unbiased estimator for the population variance is

$$
\widehat{\sigma^2} = S^2 = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i - \bar{X})^2.
$$

Therefore, a valid estimator for $\text{var}(\bar{X})$ is
$$
\widehat{\text{var}(\bar{X})} = \frac{S^2}{n} = \frac{1}{n(n-1)} \sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i - \bar{X})^2,
$$

and a valid estimator for $\text{s.e.}(\bar{X})$ is $\sqrt{\widehat{\text{var}(\bar{X})}}$. Now just apply this idea to your setting.

Comment: Thanks! But for for any $X_i$ (not Normal), why the estimate of $Var[\theta_i-\theta]$ is still $\frac{1}{n-1}\sum (\theta_i-\bar \theta)^2$?

Comment: @Hermi I haven't used normality anywhere in my answer, the sample variance is defined for any distribution of the $X_i$ and is always unbiased for the true variance. Further, $\text{Var}(\theta_i -\theta) = \text{Var}(\theta_i)$ since $\theta$ is a constant